# Loading PHP in Action Script 2.0

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Okay, I created a flash register for my website, it's very simple.

This is the main code:

```
var LoadRegisterVaribles:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
LoadRegisterVaribles.onData = function(Varibles:String) {
    error_mc.error_txt.text = Varibles;
};
LoadRegisterVaribles.load(
    "http://216.120.248.106/register/register.php?username=" + Username_mc.name_txt.text +
    "&password=" + Password_mc.pass_txt.text +
    "&email=" + Email_mc.email_txt.text + 
    "&color=" + _root.color_txt.text + "");
```

What it does is load the register.php and adds the extensions in a fancy flash GUI.

Works perfectly; But when I upload it to my website http://216.120.248.106/, or www.spuffle.in, it does not connect. **I have crossdomains.xml, that allow (*)** all in every directory, but does not work, the cross domains worked for other things I have on my site, so they are configured properly. **I also have Security.AllowDomains**

```
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.in'); 
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.me'); 
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.us'); 
Security.allowDomain('play.spuffle.me');
Security.allowDomain('play.spuffle.in');
Security.allowDomain('play.spuffle.us');
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.me/play/');
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.in/play/');
Security.allowDomain('spuffle.us/play/');
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.in'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.me'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.us'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.me/play/');
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.in/play/');
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.us/play/');
Security.allowDomain('media.spuffle.in/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('media.spuffle.me/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('media.spuffle.us/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.in/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.me/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('www.spuffle.us/media/'); 
Security.allowDomain('*.spuffle.in/*/'); 
Security.allowDomain('*.spuffle.me/*/'); 
Security.allowDomain('*.spuffle.us/*/'); 
Security.allowDomain('216.120.248.106'); 
Security.allowDomain('216.120.248.106/register/'); 
Security.allowDomain('216.120.248.106/register/Pages/'); 
Security.allowDomain('216.120.248.106/register/register.php');
```

What can I do??

Answer (score 0):

When you embed the SWF on the HTML page, try setting the allownetworking parameter: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS1EFE2EDA-026D-4d14-864E-79DFD56F87C6.html